# Ceph gatherkeys KeyNotFoundError: Could not find keyring file: /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring on host node1

Tags: debian, distributed-system, ceph

I have started learning Ceph and got an error too quickly. I have spent about 4 days to solve the problem but unfortunately without success.
I read official documentation about [quick ceph deploy](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-ceph-deploy/) and I get always the same error in 5th point.
This just do not work when I setup public_network in ceph.conf:

```
ceph-deploy mon create-initial
```

because **ceph-deploy gatherkeys** do not work.
It always show me the same error (I have tried on Debian 8.2 and CentOS 7):

> [ceph_deploy.gatherkeys] [WARNIN] Unable to find
>   /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring on node1 [ceph_deploy] [ERROR ]
>   KeyNotFoundError: Could not find keyring file:
>   /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring on host node1

I have 4 nodes like in tutorial:
admin-node, node1, node2, node3
All have ssh conection without password.
My steps:
1. **ceph-deploy new node1** (OK)
2. cange ceph.conf in my-cluster folder:
*osd_pool_default_size = 2*
*public_network = 10.0.0.0/24*
(OK)
3. **ceph-deploy install admin-node node1 node2 node3** (OK)
4. **ceph-deploy mon create-initial** (ERROR)
Can somebody explain me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been happened because in the ceph.conf you must set mon ip in the public network not in the private. And I had mon ip : 192.168.57.101 (which is the private) but public network was: 10.0.2.0/24.

Comment: It did not work for me. I instead touched keyring file on monitor. Installation went well.

Comment: @VishalKanaujia Does it caused any issue?

Comment: @DeepJoshi: No, I did not get any problem.